# Blank Search - Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I'm trying to implement the Semantic-UI search module in my app prototype.

But it's showing the results as a blank component ->

[LINK](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10917069_910353682331277_6323366442239061271_n.jpg?oh=eddf6349d77155e328a3fcbc8affbb13&oe=5538F404&__gda__=1429260476_254cc1f8944ab05f1fafd180854f5bfb)

The app is running with the Node-Webkit

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.ui.search.agendamento').search({
                source : agendamento,
                searchFields   : [
                    'patient',
                ],
                searchFullText: false
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="ui fluid search agendamento">
                    <div class="ui icon input">
                        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Buscar consulta">
                        <i class="search icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't do "solved" here when you answer your own question. You can either answer your question and mark it as accepted, or close the question. I'm rolling back the last edit.

Comment: Ah, ok ... Thanks for the tip, quite new using stackoverflow system :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was in the result json array from the Semantic-UI Search.

It needs to be formated correctly like:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "Result Title",
      "url": "/optional/url/on/click",
      "image": "optional-image.jpg",
      "price": "Optional Price"
      "description": "Optional Description"
    },
    {
      "title": "Result Title",
      "description": "Result Description"
    }
  ],
  // optional action below results
  "action": {
    "url": '/path/to/results'
    "text": "View all 202 results"
  }
}
```